# Problems with saving content of web page in html

Tags: html, twitter

I make request on twitter to find tweets for a certain period. After that I am starting to scroll page down to last twit. Next I am saving a html code of this page (right click -> save as...). Only the latest tweets are shown in this html file. How to save all tweets in html format?

Answer (score 0):

Likely Twitter adds to / removes from their html code dynamically. Likely it uses infinite scroll with seemingly endless pages. When using a browser you only see a "snapshot" of all tweets and it will never be possible to save them all. I way to proof or check this is by using your browser's inspector and then scroll. I never tried but there in the code inspector you can see what is added / removed or kept hidden. Javascript is reponsible for what you see and what you can save as..

With Firefox Ctrl+Shift+C I found the HTML code marked as 'aria-label="Timeline: Your Home Timeline" '. Under it you find the visible tweets. When you scroll you only see the ones that can save in a file. There are only eleven tweets here. When you scroll a number are added and removed but only a reduced number is available.

The only way to see all tweets is when Twitter allows you access to their tweet database, may be through the Programmers Interface, but still then there would be too many to save them all.

Comment: Thank you for answer

Comment: When you consider it the correct answer, could you mark it as such? Thank you!